# Way to speed up time inside Docker?

Tags: docker

Suppose I have an app that does something on a timer every second. Is there a way to make the timer tick 10 times a second using Docker? So the app appears to run faster to anyone outside the Docker container.

Comment: Is the timer inside the app (your app runs some code each second)? Or is the timer a different application that calls your app every second?

Comment: It is a regular OS timer.

Answer (score 2):

Docker containers share the host's kernel and clock.  Time is the same inside and outside the container.  If a privileged container changes the time, it will change the time for the entire system.  You can't make the clock in a container run at a different speed or otherwise show a different time from the host (up to time zones).

Answer (score 2):

@David Maze's answer is great, that's exactly why I asked for more details about the timer :)

Just to add some ideas, I think there could be 2 ways to solve the problem:

1. Include logic in the app itself to execute the required instructions in the required time interval;
2. Build a second app to orchestrate the execution of the logical app, according to the set time interval.